# Best way to get credit score (e.g. FICO) programmatically

Tags: .net, finance

Has anyone used one of the big 3 credit agencies and interfaced to them to get a Credit Report? We need to do in house financing and would like to automate the credit check. .NET preferred.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to a similar question asked on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220770/is-there-a-webservice-available-for-checking-a-persons-credit-score).

Most likely it will be the best to interface with a third party to pull the credit score, working directly with the bureaus can be a bit of a pain dealing with certifications and little intricacies with each bureaus format.